# jQuery .on('click', function()) not working with bootstrap-datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm kinda new to using jQuery and I'm using Bootstrap DateTimePicker to display a calendar and I want to retrieve the currently selected date but for some reason the .on('click') function doesn't seem to work when I click on the days.

This is what the html code looks like:

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div id="datetimepicker"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And what I would like to do would be something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datetimepicker').on('click', '.day', function() {
        // Get the selected date.
        var date = $(this).val();
    });
});
```

The bootstrap html for a single day is like the following:

```
<td data-action="selectDay" data-day="10/26/2016" class="day active">26</td>
<td data-action="selectDay" data-day="10/27/2016" class="day today">27</td>
<td data-action="selectDay" data-day="10/28/2016" class="day">28</td>
```

So essentially what I'm looking for is the contents of data-day of the active day.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hlynurstef/80kLcj1q/2/)

Comment: @Hsate: below our answer is helpful pls accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the following code and it's working for multiple clicks:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        inline: true,
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
    });

    $('div tbody').on('click', 'tr > .day',function(){
        alert($(this).data().day)
    })
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/12r8psoz/)

To access the data stored in `data` attribute in the html elements, you can search and read more about it on jQuery .data()

Comment: glad that i helped :)

Comment: Only thing though is that now Bootstrap doesn't update the currently selected day to be displayed as blue... :/

Comment: nevermind... it turned out to be an easy fix: https://jsfiddle.net/hlynurstef/zpvsrdhp/2/

Comment: i made an update: https://jsfiddle.net/12r8psoz/, this removes return false

Comment: While this actually works, the picker has a [`dp.change`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dpchange) event that should be used to get date the user selected. This way you get a copy of the moment object that the picker use as model instead of the string.

Comment: @VincenzoC thanks for pointing that out, i didn't know about it

Answer (score 0):

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        inline: true,
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
    });

    $('div tbody').on('click','td', function(e) {
     alert($(this).attr('data-day'));
    });
});
```

Try below fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/80kLcj1q/8/

Comment: @Hsate:If answer is helpful pls accept the answer :)

Comment: This only works once and it only gives me the day, not the year and month as well. In the bootstrap the day is marked like this "<td data-action="selectDay" data-day="10/26/2016" class="day active">26</td>" and I would like to get the contents of data-day which is "10/26/2016" and I would like to be able to do it again and again, not just once.

Comment: Also it doesn't seem to work if I click on the month, pick another month (or the same month again) and then click on a day.

Comment: @HaSte : yes , you are correct. I am update my answer .